# what is the meaning of getting ahead of oneself

Tags: meaning, phrasal-verbs

I read this sentence in a book:

> I'm getting ahead of myself

I was wondering what is the real message author would have sent to his readers. Does it mean, I wrote something incredibly clever or smart that I have to congratulate with myself. So, Is it a way to say: "I've done my best and I had a proof about that, going further my known boundaries" or a simple link sentence to carry on with some items to talk about?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Is it a text book? I think that the simplest explanation is that the author is introducing some terms that would be further explained in the following chapters. Or, quoting @Astralbee, "that he had just begun to touch on things that ought to have been saved for later"

Comment: Without context, this seems answerable with a dictionary (Cambridge Dictionary: [get ahead of yourself](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/get-ahead-of-yourself)). We can't tell you about the author's message, or specifically, why he felt like saying this without any additional context. You can [edit] your post to include more details, like a portion of the surrounding text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It generally means that you are starting to think about future stages of something that are nowhere in sight, or perhaps actually doing something too early.

One example might be someone who just started dating someone but is already wondering about where they might live once they get married. Another example might be someone who is thinking about going on vacation and is thinking about packing their suitcase before they even got a passport or bought a ticket.

When someone says "I'm getting ahead of myself" it generally marks a realisation that they have lost sight of the present.

Comment: But can it mean that the author is introducing some terms that would be futher explained in the following chapters?

Comment: @RubioRic Yes, it could mean that he had just begun to touch on things that ought to have been saved for later. In everyday speech it is sort of an admission of a mistake, but written it is often a "literary device".

Comment: As I grasped from your explanations, I think it is related to a list of elements that he has been introducing, in a row. So, he wrote this sentence after the first element, belonging to a list of 3 bullets.